# test if the solution & SQL understanding is correct

Tags: postgresql, rdbms

Employee table-  has several attributes such as EMP_ID, TITLE, DEPARTMENT, etc. a date column enabling us to know when was it updated.

what does this query do?

```
SELECT emp_id
      ,COUNT(*) as COUNT_PROFILE_CHANGE 
FROM   Employee
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC
        ,1 DESC
```

Comment: What if a user changes profile several times one day?

Comment: Also, your query is tagged with four different DBMS. If it is a general question you can tag your query with `RDBMS` instead. You should also include NOT NULL constraints and keys for your table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why distinct is needed in the count. If the table is defined as in your post:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
( EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR
, TITLE VARCHAR(30)
, DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(30)
, ACTIVE BOOLEAN
, LOCATION VARCHAR
, EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE
);
```

then an employee can exist several times each data:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE 
    (EMPLOYEE_ID,TITLE,DEPARTMENT,ACTIVE,LOCATION,EFFECTIVE_DATE)
VALUES ('Alice','Agnet','AD',TRUE,'APAC','2018-11-27')
     , ('Alice','Agnet','AD',TRUE,'APAC','2018-11-27')
```

Your query won't capture that. Neither will it handle a situation where EFFECTIVE_DATE is null:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE 
    (EMPLOYEE_ID)
VALUES ('Alice'),('Alice'),('Alice');
```

If the table is defined in a more sane way:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
( EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR NOT NULL
, TITLE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
, DEPARTMENT VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
, ACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL
, LOCATION VARCHAR NOT NULL
, EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
,     PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID, EFFECTIVE_DATE)
);
```

We know for sure that an employee can only change their profile once a day. It is then not necessary to count distinct dates (you don't have to count dates at all):

```
SELECT employee_id
      ,COUNT(*) as COUNT_PROFILE_CHANGE 
FROM   Employee
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY 2 DESC
        ,1 DESC
```